# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PicturesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, upload

I'm trying to implement a picture upload feature (without a gem), and when I go to press submit after selecting a photo I get this error:

```
Ac
tiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PicturesController#create
unknown attribute 'picture' for Picture.

Extracted source (around line #13):

  def create
    # make a new picture with what picture_params returns (which is a method we're calling)
    **@picture = Picture.new(picture_params)** << where i'm getting the error
    if @picture.save
      # if the save for the picture was successful, go to index.html.erb
      redirect_to pictures_url
```

How do I set up my environment so my photos get saved in the database?

Controller:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end

  def new
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def create
    # make a new picture with what picture_params returns (which is a method we're calling)
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      # if the save for the picture was successful, go to index.html.erb
      redirect_to pictures_url
    else
      # otherwise render the view associated with the action :new (i.e. new.html.erb)
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
      redirect_to "/pictures/#{@picture.id}"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    redirect_to pictures_url
  end

  private
  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:artist, :title, :url, :picture)
  end

end
```

migration:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :artist
      t.string :title
      t.string :url
      t.string :pictures

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I added t.string :pictures manually by editing the file, does it still work this way or is there a command I need to run?

My form:

```
<container>
<center>
<%= form_for @picture do |f| %>
  <input type="file" multiple>  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <p>Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
  <button type="submit"> <%= f.submit "Save" %> Upload </button>
</form>
<% end %>
</container>
```

I'm using a simple drag and drop upload.
Thank you for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: You added file to exisiting migration. Is that migration already pushed to the production or git? If so, you should not do this and generate a new migration instead. If this is a new migration (not pushed anywhere - exists only locally), but has been run already you need to run `rake db:migrate:redo`. As Pavan mentioned in the answer, you also would prefer to name this column `picture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PicturesController#create
>
> unknown attribute 'picture' for Picture

You have `:pictures` instead `:picture` in your ***migration file*** and you are using `:picture` in `picture_params` method.

Do `rake db:rollback`, change it to `:picture` and do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: thanks! i edited it and ran db:migrate but nothing appeared in the command line - i assume it went smoothly. im still getting the same error though :(

Comment: @icecreamrabbit Did you run `rake db:rollback` before editing the file and running `rake db:migrate`?